# How to verify XAdES signature of a document?

Tags: xml, signature

I'm looking for software (or an online service on a web page) that can verify signatures of XML documents/files according to XAdES standard.

Windows or Linux environment is acceptable for SW.

Need it for a low number of files to check.

I did try a bunch of them, but they either:

- don't recognize the syntax of the file
- don't trust custom certificates that were used to sign the document
- have strange internal errors (beta software)
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

[ETSI Signature Conformance Checker](http://signatures-conformance-checker.etsi.org/pub/index.shtml) (online service) seems something like that. Requires a free registration.